# how to integrate paypal payment gateway in ios?

Tags: ios, iphone, paypal, payment-gateway, shopping-cart

I am developing one application for ios. In that user can order/purchase restaurants menu item. I don't have any idea about payment gateways. So, please How to integrate `paypal` payment gateway method? and How to implement that in my iOS app?

Please Suggest any tutorial or links. ( I am from Gujarat,India), i heard payment gateway methods depends upon the country.

Comment: Welcome to SO! To get an constructive answer you should show evidence of your own research and ask about specific problems you encountered. Question as it stands is not fit for the format of SO.

Comment: Jakub Vano, thanks for your quick reply, i have searched google, but i got some of the integration methods/code, so for that i am confusing how to integrate. Hence i posted my query over here. Thanks for your valuable reply!